# Remove particular node in border pane in javafx when stage load

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a border pane and there are components in its top, left and right side. I want to remove the components of its right side by using the id of the borderPane when the Stage is a load. how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you should write your code in the initialize method, it will be implemented as soon as the Stage is loaded

first:

```
public class your_class implements Initializable{
//your code
}
```

then you will need to  generate the implemented method

Right-click -> Generate -> implemented methods

it would be like

```
 @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lookup(String selector) to find and remove it like that

```
borderRighSide.setId("right");
rootBorder.getChildren().remove(rootBorder.lookup("#right"));
```